# How to format the current date and time in SQL but to only include the time by itself?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm not sure how to format the 'default sysdate' to only have the time bit when ran?

So the output would be the current time '15:20:52' without the date.

I am using sql plus.

When creating the table, like this:

```
create table timeslot
(
tsdate default sysdate not null,
tstime default sysdate not null)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just use `sysdate` for the `DEFAULT` and extract the portion you need when querying the table. You can also create a view, that selects from the table and extracts the needed portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLPLUS` tag means "Oracle".

As Oracle doesn't provide "time" datatype, you would use a single column:

```
SQL> create table timeslot
  2    (id   number    primary key,
  3     ts   date      default sysdate not null
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into timeslot (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

What have I inserted?

```
SQL> select * From timeslot;

        ID TS
---------- --------
         1 03.06.20

SQL>
```

Oh boy, that looks ugly ... impossible to know what it really is because it can be

- March 6th 2020 or
- June 20th 2003 or
- June 3rd 1920 or ...

But, that's just because current NLS settings on my database display `date` datatype values as such. Oracle stores dates in 7 byte binary format (not recognizable by us, humans) so we have to do *something* to present those values nicely. For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From timeslot;

        ID TS
---------- ----------
         1 03.06.2020
```

OK, here's the date but- where's time?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From timeslot;

        ID TS
---------- -------------------
         1 03.06.2020 19:38:37

SQL>
```

Of course, you wouldn't `alter session` each time. You'd use `to_char` function with appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> select id,
  2         to_char(ts, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ts
  3  from timeslot;

        ID TS
---------- -------------------
         1 03.06.2020 19:38:37

SQL>
```

Or, as you wanted to *split* date and time components, you'd

```
SQL> select id,
  2         to_char(ts, 'dd.mm.yyyy') c_date,
  3         to_char(ts, 'hh24:mi:ss') c_time
  4  from timeslot;

        ID C_DATE     C_TIME
---------- ---------- --------
         1 03.06.2020 19:38:37

SQL>
```

Alternatively, create a VIEW which does that for you:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_timeslot as
  2  select id,
  3         to_char(ts, 'dd.mm.yyyy') c_date,
  4         to_char(ts, 'hh24:mi:ss') c_time
  5  from timeslot;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_timeslot;

        ID C_DATE     C_TIME
---------- ---------- --------
         1 03.06.2020 19:38:37

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **MS SQL**,try like below-

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS INPUT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108) AS EXPECTED_OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server:

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 8)
```